# Flutter Error: Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code

This is my android/build.gradle code from city travel guide android mobile application. But I have an error for here. I don't understand anything. Can you help me for this?

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Multiple task action failures occurred:
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04.
> AAR metadata file: C:\Users\berfi.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\5695d8d932d545af38bf66b725566d02\jetified-window-java-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta04.
> AAR metadata file: C:\Users\berfi.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\e4e324fde2799cc82a9b6d2e3e16efc2\jetified-window-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BU�LD FAILED in 2m 56s
  Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
  Exited (sigterm)

Answer (score 0):

There are two *build.gradle* files. One in the root *android/* folder and one in *android/app/* folder.

From what I understand from the error go to *build.gradle* file inside *android/app/build.gradle* and change the value of *minCompileSdk* from 31 to 30. The default value could be *flutter.compileSdkVersion* in that case, do the same. Replace it with 30

The error is that "The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties) is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30)."

So I'm assuming changing it from 31 to 30 should fix your error. Give it a try.